# Can anyone explain the synthesize process when using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I realize that it automatically creates a setter & getter for you but I'm uncertain how the setter actually "looks".

Also, why is it recommended that we say `@synthesize someObject = _someObject;` instead of just `@synthesize someObject;`?

Comment: The way the setter looks depends on the options that you specify with the property declaration (atomic/nonatomic/copy/etc.) As of a few months ago, `@synthesize` is optional.

Comment: It's hard to explain because they keep changing it.

Comment: @HotLicks - yeah they do!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy bit first: you don't need to `@synthesize` at all any more. If you have an `@property` and you don't synthesise it then one is implied, of the form `@synthesize someObject = _someObject;`. If you left off the `= _someObject` then you would have the same thing as `@synthesize someObject = someObject;`. The underscore version is therefore preferred because Apple has swung back to advocating underscores for instance variables and because it's consistent with the implicit type of synthesise.

The exact form of setter and getter will depend on the `atomic`, `strong`, `unsafe_unretained`, etc flags but sample nonatomic strong setter, pre-ARC is:

```
- (void)setProperty:(NSString *)newPropertyValue
{
    [newPropertyValue retain];
    [_property release];
    _property = newPropertyValue;
}
```

Note the retain always occurs before the release. Otherwise the following (which you would arrive at in a roundabout fashion rather than ever writing directly):

```
self.property = _property;
```

Would lead to `_property` potentially being deallocated before it was retained.

A sample getter (also pre-ARC) is:

```
- (NSString *)property
{
    return [[property retain] autorelease];
}
```

The `retain` ensures that the return value will persist even if the object it was queried from is deallocated. The `autorelease` ensures you return a non-owning reference (ie, the receiver doesn't explicitly have to dispose of the thing, it can just forget about it when it's done). If the thing being returned is immutable but the instance variable is mutable then it's proper form to `copy` rather than retain to ensure that what you return doesn't mutate while someone else is holding onto it.

Comment: These may very well apply to ARC as well - it's always the compiler who inserts the appropriate retain/release calls (or, more precisely, the `objc_setProperty()` runtime function) anyway.

Comment: When you say I don't need to `@synthesize` "at all" now... when did that take effect? lol

Comment: Also, when we don't `synthesize` anymore and we let XCode create the getter/setter, can we still create our own getter that would lazily instantiate?

Comment: I think I'm right to say that if you use no @synthesize at all then: (i) if there should be a setter and you haven't written a custom one then one will be added; (ii) ditto for the getter; and (iii) if at least one of those was created for you then the instance variable will also be created. So you can create your own lazy getter.

Answer (score 2):

Check leture 3 of iPad and [iPhone Application itunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255)

`_someObj` replace a memory location for store your object(a pointer).
Xcode 4 auto `@synthesize anyObject = _anyObject;` -> So you don't need to write `@synthesize` anymore.

If you have some other object or _anyMemoryLocation write before in your.m file, you can use @synthesize yourObj = _anyMemeryLocation if you don't want rewrite all name in your.m file.

Setter and getter 2 methods use to set or get your object's value outside or inside your class:

```
-(void)setObject:(ObjectType *) object;
-(void)getObject:(ObjectType *) object;
```

The key nonatomic auto generate setter and getter for you.

If you want to implement more method went setObject, you can rewrite it in your.m file

```
-(void)setObject:(ObjectType *) object{
    _object = object; //rewrite setter can done anywhere in your.m file
    //Add more method
}
```